# Cronjob calling SVN update cannot use credentials

Tags: bash, svn, cron

## Setup

I have an SVN repository that I want to update regularly (every day, every hour, etc. ). 
Thus, I wanted to use cron to automate this. 
Within this SVN repository, I can simply use `svn update .` without any problem.
Therefore, I have written this bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH="CONTENT_OF_MY_PATH_VARIABLE"
cd /path/to/svn-repo
svn update .
```

and added this line in cron

```
1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/bash /path/to/the/script.bash
```

## Problem

When `svn update .` is called via cron and the bash script, I'm receiving this error.

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://url-to-repo'
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
```

## Question

What do I have to source in the bash script additionally to make the cronjob work? 
Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: How do you authenticate with the server? Do you run this cron task as your user or as root?

Comment: I'm authenticating with user name and password. The task is run as my user.

Comment: my solution is use `--no-auth-cache` option and assign username and password via command line.